# is there any way to strip timestamp and date in a dll file in linux? is any tool available?

Tags: linux, assembly, mono, disassembly

I am trying to strip timestamp and date from a dll file.
In detail :- I am trying make file as binary reproducible
(Requirement :- whenever i clean and rebuild it ,the md5sum must match for the file)
In the above case only a dll was mismatching everytime ,the reason was the time stamp and date were differing everytime
so i tried the following
c:\temp> ildasm /all /text file1.exe | find /v "Time-date stamp:" | find /v "MVID" > file1.txt

c:\temp> ildasm /all /text file2.exe | find /v "Time-date stamp:" | find /v "MVID" > file2.txt

c:\temp> fc file1.txt file2.txt

Comparing files file1.txt and FILE2.TXT
the values were matching
so i found an equivalent in linux for Ildasm -> monodis
I was able to get the same result but I was unable to reuse the file

i tried to reassemble using ilasm but didnt work..

is there any suggestions??

Neil

Comment: This question is unclear.  DLL's are Windows only, not Linux (they are shared objects `.so`).  Also that metadata cannot be *stripped*, it can only be changed.

Comment: Strip timestamp of what? By a DLL file do you mean a windows DLL or the more generic term, called "shared object" in the Unix world?

Comment: I compile the windows dll using "mcs", a cross compiler. The dll generated is not binary reproducible because of timestamp and date information. If that is stripped the sha1sum matches for all builds. So is there a way to strip that information.

Comment: When using mono, DLLs on Linux are completely normal.

Answer (score 1):

In order to "fix" the timestamp at a given value, you can simply edit the PE32 header of the .dll/.exe file. The timestamp is a little endian 32-bit integer at offset 0x88 from the start of the file (offset 8 of the PE32 header).

However, this is only part of it. You also need to set the MVID (module version ID) of every module within the assembly. You can do this using Mono.Cecil:

```
using System;
using Mono.Cecil;

public class Program {
  public static void Main() {
    string infile = "in.exe";
    string outfile = "out.exe";
    Guid guid = Guid.Parse("12345678-1234-1234-1234-1234567890ab");
    AssemblyDefinition asm = AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly(infile);
    ModuleDefinition mod = asm.MainModule;
    mod.Mvid = guid;
    asm.Write(outfile);
  }
}
```

Note that the above code only does what you want if there's a single module in the assembly (the common case). If you have multiple modules, you need to iterate over `mod.Modules()`.

You also need to not use a fixed GUID (as above), but one that actually is different for different modules (e.g., derived from a SHA1 hash of the source code).

I trust that you understand that messing with module versioning is potentially dangerous and that such manipulations need to be done with extreme caution, especially when you accidentally generate two different assemblies with the same MVIDs.